# IE10: Unable to set any flex style properties via Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```js
var node = document.getElementById('some-object');
node.style.flex = '480px 1 0';
```

Question is, **why doesn't the snippet above work on IE 10?**

I can set the `flex` or `flexBasis` or `flexGrow` or whatsoever in IE11 and above, so why doesn't it work in IE 10?

Comment: That is an incorrect value for `flex` and IE 10 only supports the `-ms-` prefixed version of flex (partial support)

Comment: As IE10 use prefixed properties for Flexbox (the older version of it), you need to do the same with your script.

    `var node = document.getElementById('some-object');
    node.style.msFlex = '1 0 480px';     /* flex: <flex-grow> <flex-shrink> <flex-basis>  */`

_And note, the `flex-basis` value should be last_

Comment: @LGSon that's actually the method I found. No idea why I can set `msFlex` via javascript but not `msFlexBasis`. Any reason why the flex-basis needs to be last, though?

Comment: It seems to work either way (specifically setting `{???}px 0 0`, that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because flexbox styling [isn't supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in IE versions older than 11.

Comment: I'm using IE11, emulating IE10 document mode. Everything except setting `flexBasis` via Javascript seems to work.

Comment: Can I not trust the document mode emulation either?

Comment: Emulation is never as good as using the thing you're emulating.

Comment: yup, I guessed so :sadface:

Comment: This is wrong, IE10 supports Flexbox, though the older version, using prefixed properties

Comment: @LGSon: partial support != support ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus You write _isn't supported in IE versions older than 11_, which is wrong

Comment: It’s not even fully supported in 11...

Comment: No more comments from me...people can read themselves

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by IE10, have a look here which browsers support flexbox: https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox
Note, IE11 has only partial support.

Comment: This is wrong, IE10 supports Flexbox, though the older version, using prefixed properties, and IE11 supports it, though partial support due to large amount of bugs present.